# Unable to restart automount

Tags: automount

I am trying to restart `automount` as it consumes a lot of CPU:

```
Tasks: 2392 total,   7 running, 2352 sleeping,  25 stopped,   8 zombie
Cpu(s):  9.3% us, 28.5% sy,  0.0% ni, 61.5% id,  0.2% wa,  0.2% hi,  0.2% si
Mem:  15799928k total, 11029764k used,  4770164k free,   162424k buffers
Swap: 22773752k total,  7303680k used, 15470072k free,  2628508k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 5939 root      25   0 27112 1556  952 S 97.2  0.0   3155:01 automount
```

I get the following error, however:

```
Stopping automount:umount2: Device or resource busy
umount: /proj: device is busy
umount2: Device or resource busy
umount: /tool: device is busy
[FAILED]
Starting automount: /tool: mount failed!
failed to load map: /usr/sbin/automount --timeout=300 /tool yp auto.tool -DOS=k26_g23_64 tcp,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,timeo=600,retrans=2
/proj: mount failed!
failed to load map: /usr/sbin/automount --timeout=300 /proj yp auto.proj -DOS=k26_g23_64 tcp,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,timeo=600,retrans=2
/home: mount failed!
```

`ps -ef | grep automount | egrep -v grep` then gives me:

```
root      5885     1  0 Sep13 ?        00:02:11 /usr/sbin/automount --timeout=300 /tool yp auto.tool -DOS=k26_g23_64 tcp,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,timeo=600,retrans=2
root      5939     1 12 Sep13 ?        2-04:45:46 /usr/sbin/automount --timeout=300 /proj yp auto.proj -DOS=k26_g23_64 tcp,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,timeo=600,retrans=2
```

Comment: If reboot an option, I will go for that. Anyway, what OS is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And try to kill automount first before restarting autofs.

If you can't kill it, then a reboot is a must. Try to "kill -15 5885" and not "-9", where 5885 is the autmount pid as per above.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't kill it i were you :> Propably an **application is using /proj** (in terms of open files), and if you umount it you may have a really bad experience.

Try to find which application this is (using lsof) , **kill the application** and try to **umount** the directory **afterwards**.

Comment: +1 for lsof... a good app